# Auto-populate cells based on previous cell values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have two columns with information. Values in Column B have been manually added to match the values in Column A.

Is it possible to have a function that auto-populates column B with the right values based on what comes before the new rows (i.e 998, 999)?

Column A might have a different order each time new rows get added.

```
        A         B        
     Product  Category    
  1   Apple    Fruit  
  2   Orange   Fruit    
  3   Beets    Vegetable  
  4   Cake     Dessert    
  5   Carrot   Vegetable  
  9   Apple    Fruit
...
998   Beets    ?
999   Apple    ?
```

**Is this possible in Google Sheets?**

Comment: Hoping to find a good solution to this too.... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- yes it is if the "sample" (`A2:B6`) is large enough:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A7:A, A2:B6, 2, 0)))
  ```

  [image: 0]